# Xamarin Admob RewardedVideoAd Code Error 0 & 3

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to use AdMob in my Xamarin project. I aim at displaying a rewarded video on my app. I have issues I can't resolve and that I would like to share with you. Here is my environment :

- Xamarin v4.0.1.96
- Xamarin Android v6.0.1.10
- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads v27.0.0

I always execute the project on a real device. In case the problem comes from the debug environment, I have published the app on the store and I got the same problem as in local.

```
using System;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Gms.Ads;

    public class ReloadCreditActivity : AppCompatActivityBase, IRewardedVideoAdListener
    {
        public IRewardedVideoAd RewardedVideoAd { get; set; }
        public Button DisplayVideoButton { get; set; }

        private static string AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX25/XXXXXXXX99";
        private bool _isRewardedVideoLoading;
        private static object _lock = new object();
        protected IRewardedVideoAd _rewardedVideoAd;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ReloadCreditLayout);

            DisplayVideoButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.tabCreditFreemieum_DisplayVideo);

            RewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.GetRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
            RewardedVideoAd.RewardedVideoAdListener = this;
            LoadRewardedVideoAd();

            DisplayVideoButton.Click += (o, e) =>
            {
                ShowRewardedVideo();
            };
        }

        public void LoadRewardedVideoAd()
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (!_isRewardedVideoLoading && !RewardedVideoAd.IsLoaded)
                {
                    _isRewardedVideoLoading = true;
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.PutBoolean("_noRefresh", true);
                    var adMobAdapter = new AdMobAdapter();
                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        //.AddTestDevice(AdRequest.DeviceIdEmulator)
                        //.AddTestDevice("FE5692B3DAD1B4CE3BE3BDA2FF4B6103")
                        //.AddNetworkExtrasBundle(adMobAdapter.Class, extras)
                        .Build();
                    RewardedVideoAd.UserId = "pub-74XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                    RewardedVideoAd.LoadAd(AD_UNIT_ID, adRequest);
                }
            }
        }

        public void ShowRewardedVideo()
        {
            if (RewardedVideoAd.IsLoaded)
            {
                RewardedVideoAd.Show();
            }
        }

        public void OnRewarded(IRewardItem reward)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, string.Format("OnRewarded ! currency: {0} amount: {1}", reward.GetType(), reward.Amount), ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoAdClosed()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "OnRewardedVideoAdClosed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            LoadRewardedVideoAd();
        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                _isRewardedVideoLoading = false;
            }
            Toast.MakeText(this, "OnRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad Code error : " + errorCode, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "OnRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoAdLoaded()
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                _isRewardedVideoLoading = false;
            }
            Toast.MakeText(this, "OnRewardedVideoAdLoaded", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoAdOpened()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "OnRewardedVideoAdOpened", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoStarted()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "OnRewardedVideoStarted", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

When I navigate on this page, the app always raise the OnRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad() callback. I used to get the error code 0 but currently I got the error code 3.

I check the error on Android Device Logging

```
05-10 11:45:31.600 I/Ads     (14764): Starting ad request.
05-10 11:45:31.600 I/Ads     (14764): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("FE5692B3DAD1B4CE3BE3BDA2FF4B6103") to get test ads on this device.
    ...
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764): Could not instantiate mediation adapter: com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdapter. com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdapter
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764): Fail to instantiate adapter com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdapter
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764): android.os.RemoteException
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zzag(Unknown Source)
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zzae(Unknown Source)
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzem$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
...
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764): Could not instantiate mediation adapter: com.fuse.mediation.FuseAdapter. com.fuse.mediation.FuseAdapter
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764): Fail to instantiate adapter com.fuse.mediation.FuseAdapter
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764): android.os.RemoteException
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zzag(Unknown Source)
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zzae(Unknown Source)
...
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764): Could not instantiate mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.chartboost.ChartboostAdapter. com.google.ads.mediation.chartboost.ChartboostAdapter
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764): Fail to instantiate adapter com.google.ads.mediation.chartboost.ChartboostAdapter
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764): android.os.RemoteException
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zzag(Unknown Source)
05-10 11:45:31.910 W/Ads     (14764):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zzae(Unknown Source)
...
05-10 11:45:31.920 W/Ads     (14764): Could not instantiate mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.unity.UnityAdapter. com.google.ads.mediation.unity.UnityAdapter
05-10 11:45:31.920 W/Ads     (14764): Fail to instantiate adapter com.google.ads.mediation.unity.UnityAdapter
05-10 11:45:31.920 W/Ads     (14764): android.os.RemoteException
05-10 11:45:31.920 W/Ads     (14764):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zzag(Unknown Source)
05-10 11:45:31.920 W/Ads     (14764):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zzae(Unknown Source)
...
05-10 11:45:31.920 W/Ads     (14764): Could not instantiate mediation adapter: com.vungle.mediation.VungleAdapter. com.vungle.mediation.VungleAdapter
05-10 11:45:31.920 W/Ads     (14764): Fail to instantiate adapter com.vungle.mediation.VungleAdapter
05-10 11:45:31.920 W/Ads     (14764): android.os.RemoteException
05-10 11:45:31.920 W/Ads     (14764):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zzag(Unknown Source)
05-10 11:45:31.920 W/Ads     (14764):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zzae(Unknown Source)
...
05-10 11:45:31.920 W/Ads     (14764): Failed to load ad: 3
```

I told myself that maybe it is a problem on my admob configuration with the advertiser, so here is my settings:

[image]

Maybe I did something wrong on the settings of the advertiser so here are my advertiser.

AdColony :
[image]

Chartboost : 
[image]

Vungle : 
[image]

Please, give me your feedback. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nobody have a comment ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that in your Xamarin project you do not have the mediation adapters defined.  These are provided by the various ad agencies (like vUngle) in their SDKs.  Unfortunately, none of them currently provide Xamarin-compatible SDKs, so you have to following the steps for importing foreign assemblies into Xamarin.  There are a few people attempting to do this (try searching the Xamarin forums) but I have not seen anyone post a working solution.